# VMWare warns about consolidation after cancelling snapshot creation

Tags: vmware, debian-jessie, snapshot

I'm using VMWare vSphere client on Windows 10 to connect to my company DC (OVH).

I wanted to create a snapshot of a VM (Debian) before updating the packages.

So I tried to create a snapshot of a running VM but I noticed that it slowers/blocks the VM (impact on the website).

I decided to cancel the task but since then there is a warning about disk consolidation needed.

```
Error Stack:

An error occurred while taking a snapshot: msg.snapshot.error-CANCELLED.
An error occurred while saving snapshot file "/vmfs/volumes/01a2faad-bed2417d/new VM/new VM-Snapshot10.vmsn".
An error occurred while saving the snapshot: msg.snapshot.error-CANCELLED.
```

The VM needs to be up without down-time.

What can I do ?

I'm a newbie :)

Comment: I am fairly new with VMWare myself, but its possible that there is still a "delta" file somewhere.  Snapshot basically stores all the changes you make to the machine after the snapshot in a separate file known as a "Delta".  Consolidating merges the files together.  Try opening the snapshot manager and deleting the snapshot the process may have created (If one is present)

Comment: If you're updating packages, you may well need to reboot, so zero down-time will be unattainable. Taking a snapshot is bound to have an impact on performance, and it can take a long time. To resolve the warning, see [this reference](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/470422).

Comment: @CheesusCrust I don't have it in the Snapshot manager. I added the error stack

Comment: I found in a [VMWare Forum post](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2458200#2458200) that recommended creating a new snapshot (letting it finish) and then deleting it might fix the problem as well.  Worth a try?